# web development: using background video is blocking firefox

Tags: firefox, video

i'm developing a website which is using a background video for the home page. 
that video has pretty small filesize (about ~300 kb) and the problem is that it is kinda blocking firefox - which means when clicking a link to a different page, it takes about 10 seconds until firefox will start loading it. i've checked the taskmanager, plugincontainer.exe is eating ~26% cpu on my machine.
any ideas how to optimize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I googled optimising video backgrounds, and it gave me this page, it talks about streaming videos and how to optimise it, its essentially what will be causing the problem I would assume.

http://www.reelseo.com/streaming-video-optimization/